# How can we populate data in dropdown list from more than one table based on different input parameter on RMA Line form in Infor Syteline(9.00.03)ERP

Tags: sql-server, erp

We have added two custom fields on `RMA Line` form in `Syteline(9.00.03) ERP`.
The first field is `Reason Type` and the Second is `Return Reason`. We have five different custom tables for `Return Reason`.
When we select a `Reason Type`, based on  `Reason Type` data will populate in the `Return Reason` drop-down list from a different table.

Data can come directly from a table or the joining of two tables.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is not at all clear. Are you trying to implement 2 dropdowns that populates the second based on the selected value in the first one?

Comment: @sean it is a simple question,when we writing a code in Java,C#, Vb.net for UI. But it looks tricky when you work in mongoose platform. We can not add directly Sp output to drop-down list. this question is related to Infor Syteline ERP.

Answer (score 0):

We should write a Stored procedure having one input parameter called Reason Type.

CREATE PROC GetReturnReason
(
 @ReturnType NVARCHAR(10)  -- Value can be A,B,C,D,E
)

AS

IF @ReturnType = 'A'

```
  SELECT ReturnReason FROM Table1  -- Write your own query
```

ELSE IF @ReturnType = 'B'

```
SELECT ReturnReason FROM Table2
```

ELSE IF @ReturnType = 'C'

```
 SELECT ReturnReason FROM Table3
```

ELSE IF @ReturnType = 'D'

SELECT T1.ReturnReason AS ReturnReason FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.item = T2.item

ELSE IF @ReturnType = 'E'

```
SELECT ReturnReason FROM Table4
```

1. Create one Custom load method and link the above Stored procedure with CLM in IDO.
2. Go to the dropdown list and create listsource using CLM and pass the input parameter(Reason Type) to CLM.
3. Save the changes and logout from the syteline.
4. Discard the Ido.
5. Login into the syteline and check it will work as per your requirement.